# CSS3 selector for searching numbers in element's ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to give a custom CSS property to the specified range of the elements identified by number in id.

HTML:

```
<div id="game">
  <div id="game-board-field-1-street-name"></div>
  <div id="game-board-field-2-street-name"></div>
  <div id="game-board-field-3-street-name"></div>
  <div id="game-board-field-4-street-name"></div>
  ...
  <div id="game-board-field-11-street-name"></div>
  <div id="game-board-field-12-street-name"></div>
  <div id="game-board-field-13-street-name"></div>
  <div id="game-board-field-14-street-name"></div>
  ... too many ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#game div[id$=street-name] { /* I want this selector to get applied only to streets 1-4 */
  font-size: 10px;
}

#game div[id$=street-name] { /* This one to streets 11-14 */
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Is there any ways to handle it only by CSS?

Comment: Why not just give them a CSS class in the code that generates the HTML? Using an `[id$=…]` selector just seems odd to me.

Comment: @Inerdial: Repeating same class name to every of 100+ elements is more odd than doing a selector. Compare amount of code. Think.

Comment: @Radio: How is that odd? Classes have been used to group multiple elements for decades. And it really isn't that much more code considering how long all your element IDs are already.

Comment: @BoltClock: Underline word decades. Time for progressive thinking. Big mistake here is to criticize. Got Question - Got Solution.

Comment: @Radio: I'm assuming you're generating all those <div> elements anyway. Is it that much more code to do the maths server-side and output a class name than doing it client side? It would also make the CSS clearer and less magical - there's probably a reason why streets 11-14 have to be in a bigger font, so why not give it a name?

Comment: @Radio Don't fix what isn't broken. The advantage of classes being around forever is that browsers are optimised up the wazoo to handle them. Doing something differently just because you can is how Daily WTF posts are born.

Comment: @Inerdial: No, I don't generate those. Font is just an example, there are 12+ css properties. Nothing is broken. Solution which BoltClock gave me is saving lots of traffic, which is critical on the EDGE connections. Classes will extend html too much.

Comment: @Radio If CSS classes are too much bandwidth, why use brobdingnagian identifiers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't select directly by their numbered IDs, as CSS doesn't provide dynamic attribute selectors.

However, if your structure is such that each numbered `div` corresponds to its position in the `#game` parent element, you may be able to use `:nth-child()` instead:

```css
/* First 4 elements */
#game div:nth-child(-n+4) {
  font-size: 10px;
}

/* Elements starting from the 11th and ending at the 14th */
#game div:nth-child(n+11):nth-child(-n+14) {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for agreeing in the comments above that using explicit, more manageable and semantic classes would have been reasonable too